# jQuery resize doesn't affect variable and affix

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, affix

I'm trying to make a navbar affixable at the proper scroll position.

I have a `#cover-section` element and below it, an affixable navbar.
The `#cover-section` element is resizable. when it gets resized, I want the affixing offset position to be modified as well, but the `coverHeight` variable doesn't seem to be updating. The `coverHeight` value initially is 0, and always remains zero.

How do I get the coverHeight variable within the `.resize()` function scope to actually modify the variable value that was declared outside of the event's scope?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var coverHeight;
  coverHeight = 0;

  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('#cover-section').height($(window).height() - $('#navbar').height());
    return coverHeight = $('#cover-section').height();
  });

  $('.affixable-wrapper').height($('.affixable-wrapper > .affixable').height());
  return $('.affixable-wrapper > .affixable').affix({
    offset: coverHeight
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the values of these functions to the `coverHeight` variable. Resize doesn't have a return, and if it did you aren't returning it to anything. try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var coverHeight = 0;

  $(window).resize(function() {
      $('#cover-section').height($(window).height() - $('#navbar').height());
      coverHeight = $('#cover-section').height();
  });
});
```

If you are only binding to resize to fire affix, then:

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('.affixable-wrapper > .affixable').affix({
        offset: $('#cover-section').height($(window).height() -  
$('#navbar').height());
        }); 
    });
```

You don't need the `coverHeight` var if you are only setting and calling it in the same function

Comment: so coffeescript's implicit return is the problem

Comment: I'm not getting any different behavior from this. I need the affixable portion code to reference the `coverHeight` variable. Should I be putting the "affixable" code elsewhere?

Comment: updated the answer, you dont need the var if you only want to bind to resize to call affix

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't working either. affix is an event listener, just like resize is. How would I use setTimeout to make sure the affix function is accessing the updated dom element (and the dom element's new sizes)?